# In Selenium for Python, how can I get an element's attribute rather than its property?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute, getpropertyvalue

According to the docs, [get_attribute](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) actually returns the property rather than the attribute, unless the property doesn't exist, in which case it falls back to the attribute.

[get_property](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_property) will always return the property.

Is there a way to always get the attribute? I find it weird that a function named "get_attribute" would prioritize the property value over the attribute value.

Answer (score 3):

### get_attribute(attribute_name)

[get_attribute(attribute_name)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) gets the given `attribute` or `property` of the element.

This method will first try to return the value of a property with the given name. If a property with that name doesn’t exist, it returns the value of the `attribute` with the same name. If there’s no `attribute` with that name, **`None`** is returned.

Values which are considered truthy, that is equals `true` or `false`, are returned as booleans. All other non-`None` values are returned as strings. For attributes or properties which do not exist, `None` is returned.

- Args:

  ```
  attribute_name - Name of the attribute/property to retrieve.
  ```
- Example:

  ```
  # Check if the "active" CSS class is applied to an element.
  is_active = "active" in target_element.get_attribute("class")
  ```

---

### get_property(property_name)

[get_property(property_name)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_property) gets the given property of the element.

- Args:

  ```
  property_name - Name of the property to retrieve.
  ```
- Example:

  ```
  text_length = target_element.get_property("text_length")
  ```

Still sounds similar? Read below ...

---

### [Attributes and properties](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties)

When the browser loads the page, it **parses** the HTML and generates DOM objects from it. For element nodes, most standard HTML attributes automatically become properties of DOM objects.

For instance, if the tag is:

```
<body id="page">
```

then the DOM object has `body.id="page"`.

> **Note**: The attribute-property mapping is not one-to-one!

---

### [HTML attributes](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties#html-attributes)

In HTML, tags may have attributes. When the browser parses the HTML to create DOM objects for tags, it recognizes standard attributes and creates DOM properties from them.

So when an element has id or another standard attribute, the corresponding property gets created. But that doesn’t happen if the attribute is non-standard.

> **Note**: A standard attribute for one element can be unknown for another one. For instance, `type` is standard attribute for [`<input>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlinputelement) tag, but not for [`<body>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlbodyelement) tag. Standard attributes are described in the specification for the corresponding element class.

So, if an attribute is non-standard, there won’t be a DOM-property for it. In that case all attributes are accessible by using the following methods:

- `elem.hasAttribute(name)`: checks for existence.
- `elem.getAttribute(name)`: gets the value.
- `elem.setAttribute(name, value)`: sets the value.
- `elem.removeAttribute(name)`: removes the attribute.

An example of reading a non-standard property:

```
<body something="non-standard">
  <script>
    alert(document.body.getAttribute('something')); // non-standard
  </script>
</body>
```

---

### [Property-attribute synchronization](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties#property-attribute-synchronization)

When a standard attribute changes, the corresponding property is auto-updated, and (with some exceptions) vice versa. But there are exclusions, for instance `input.value` synchronizes only from `attribute` -> to `property`, but not back. This **feature** actually comes in handy, because the user may modify value, and then after it, if we want to recover the "original" value from HTML, it’s in the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm not sure if any of this actually answers the question? Your code example at the bottom is JavaScript, but the question is about Selenium for Python. I already know the difference between attributes and properties and how the synchronization works; my question is about how I can retrieve the attribute in Selenium for Python.