# Extracting URL from href attribute of specific <a> tag using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract a URL from the href attribute of a specific  tag on a webpage using Python and Selenium. The  tag has a href attribute that starts with "javascript:SetAzurePlayerFileName", and I want to extract the URL that follows this string.

Here's an example of the  tag (from this [page](https://main.knesset.gov.il/activity/committees/insolvency/pages/committeetvarchive.aspx?topicid=19798)):

```
<a href="javascript:SetAzurePlayerFileName('https://video.knesset.gov.il/KnsVod/_definst_/mp4:CMT/CmtSession_2081117.mp4/manifest.mpd',...">Link text</a>
```

I want to extract the URL `"https://video.knesset.gov.il/KnsVod/_definst_/mp4:CMT/CmtSession_2081117.mp4/manifest.mpd"`.

I've tried using BeautifulSoup with the requests library, but it seems the content of the webpage is loaded dynamically with JavaScript, so requests can't fetch the  tag.

I then tried using Selenium with ChromeDriver, but I encountered issues with the WebDriver and the browser driver. I also tried setting the User-Agent header and waiting for the  tag to be present with WebDriverWait, but I still couldn't find the element.

I switched to Firefox and GeckoDriver, but I'm still unable to find the element, and I'm getting a "NoSuchElementError".

Here's the latest version of my script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

def get_url_from_webpage(url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    try:
        a_tag = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[starts-with(@href, "javascript:SetAzurePlayerFileName")]')))
        href = a_tag.get_attribute('href')
        match = re.search(r"javascript:SetAzurePlayerFileName\('(.*)',", href)
        if match:
            return match.group(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return None
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can successfully extract the URL from the href attribute of this  tag?

Note: I believe that the main issue is that the content doesn't seem to be loaded in this mode of Python, rather than a problem with the regex or the XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:SetAzurePlayerFileName('https://video.knesset.gov.il/KnsVod/_definst_/mp4:CMT/CmtSession_2081117.mp4/manifest.mpd',...">Link text</a>
```

To print the value of the *href* attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and [*get_attribute()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55844938/7429447) method and then using [split()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59078966/7429447) with respect to the `.` character and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT* and `split('\'')`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Link text"))).get_attribute("href").split('\'')[1])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `split("'")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Link text']"))).get_attribute("href").split("'")[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Python Selenium - get href value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821486/7429447)

---

### Proof of concept

```
html = '''
    <a href="javascript:SetAzurePlayerFileName('https://video.knesset.gov.il/KnsVod/_definst_/mp4:CMT/CmtSession_2081117.mp4/manifest.mpd',...">Link text</a>
'''

print(html.split('\'')[1]) # prints -> https://video.knesset.gov.il/KnsVod/_definst_/mp4:CMT/CmtSession_2081117.mp4/manifest.mpd
print(html.split("'")[1]) # prints -> https://video.knesset.gov.il/KnsVod/_definst_/mp4:CMT/CmtSession_2081117.mp4/manifest.mpd
```

Comment: I received `TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16`

Comment: @Yanirmr I can't access the url, I simply used the HTML you provided. Checkout the answer update.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the page doesn't load while using selenium?

Comment: @Yanirmr Check if the desired element is within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) or within a [**shadowRoot**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447)